# Laravel: how to use wherePivot in Polymorphic Many to Many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I want to query where **isrecurring = 1** in my pivot table, but found no existing solution. Anyone have any experience and how to get all records that **'isrecurring' = 1** in Many-To-Many polymorphic pivot table?

```
Example.
$enroll->products->where('isrecurring', 1);

but in enrollable pivot table
-> get all records that 'isrecurring' = 1
```

My Models (without wherePivot)

```
Enroll.php
------
public function products(){
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Product', 'enrollable')->withPivot('isrecurring');
}

Product.php
----
public function enrolls(){
return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Enroll', 'enrollable')->withPivot('isrecurring');
}
```

My Database

```
enrolls
-----
id


products
----
id

enrollables
----
enroll_id
enrollable_id
enrollable_type
isrecurring    (boolean)
```

I wish to use wherePivot, but seems not working and not able to query.

```
Product.php
----
public function enrolls(){
return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Enroll', 'enrollable')->withPivot('isrecurring')->wherePivot('isrecurring', '=', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could solve it using the following:

```
//Model: User.php

public function certificates()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Certificate', 'appliable')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

> 

```
//Controller: EnrollmentController.php

$usersWithCertificates = User::whereHas('certificates', function($query){
    $query->where('status', '0');
})->with('certificates')->latest()->paginate(10);
```

use the `function($query){ }` to add your custom SQL of the pivot table

you can read more in Laravel docs here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence in the Querying Relationship Existence part